# Oracle Deref function : wrong numer or type of arguments

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create an object method in Oracle like this :

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY TheType AS
    MEMBER FUNCTION getAtt RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN DEREF(SELF.Att).Att2;
    END;
END;
/
```

But I got the following error :

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DEREF'
```

Also the type TheType is declared like that :

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TheType UNDER SuperType ();
/

...

ALTER TYPE TheType ADD ATTRIBUTE ( Att REF TheType ) CASCADE;

...

ALTER TYPE TheType 
    ADD MEMBER FUNCTION getAtt RETURN VARCHAR2
CASCADE;
```

And the definition of Supertype :

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SuperType AS OBJECT ( Att2 VARCHAR2(50) )
NOT FINAL NOT INSTANTIABLE;
/
```

I give to DEREF function a var with the right type, why this error occurs ?

It should work if I trust the [Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions054.htm#SQLRF00634)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

shift the DEREF into SQL. e.g.

```
SQL> create or replace type supertype as object ( att2 varchar2(50) )
  2  not final not instantiable;
  3  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type thetype under supertype (
  2  att ref thetype,
  3  member function getatt return varchar2);
  4  /

Type created.

SQL> show errors type thetype
No errors.
SQL> create or replace type body thetype as
  2    member function getatt return varchar2 is
  3      v_t thetype;
  4    begin
  5             select deref(self.att) into v_t from dual;
  6             return v_t.att2;
  7    end;
  8  end;
  9  /

Type body created.

SQL> show errors type body thetype
No errors.
SQL> create table thetypes of thetype;

Table created.

SQL> insert into thetypes values ('hi there', null);

1 row created.

SQL> set serverout on
SQL> declare
  2    v_t thetype;
  3  begin
  4    select thetype(null, ref(a)) into v_t from thetypes a;
  5    dbms_output.put_line(v_t.getatt);
  6  end;
  7  /
hi there

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Weldone. Separate the `.Att2`. Could this work just as easily without the `Select` or does the `DEREF` require it?

Comment: @glh its the deref that requires it. we could combine the att2 in the select too if you wanted :) i.e. `select deref(self.att).att2 into v_ret from dual; return v_ret;` would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few ideas to try and narrow down the issue:

1. To separate the `DEREF` from the `.Att2` and test to see which part of the script it doesn't like; **also**
2. Try out the `att` type using a stand-alone pl/sql to see if it returns anything.
3. If it does see if the `DEREF` works over it then; **also**
4. See if the `REF(TheType.Att2)` works outside of the type creation in a stand-alone pl/sql.

I do concur with you though there seems to be no issues in the first instance.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

We can declare REFs as variables, parameters, fields, or attributes.

```
DECLARE
  emp         employee_typ;
  emp_ref REF employee_typ;  -- creating one more type with REF
BEGIN
  SELECT REF(e) INTO emp_ref FROM employee_tab e WHERE e.employee_id = 370;
  UPDATE employee_tab e 
    SET e.address = address_typ('NIZAM', 'Hyd', 'AP', '465876')
    WHERE REF(e) = emp_ref;
END;
```

and I don't think `REF` & `DEREF` work when creating object types. It's for returning the instance value of an object.